# Get parent element on XSD validation error

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I have the following xml with unit & measure child elements.

```
<Depth>
    <measure>1.00</measure>
    <unit>in</unit>
<Depth>
<Width>
    <measure>1.00</measure>
    <unit>in</unit>
</Width>
<vendorPackHeight>
    <measure>1.00</measure>
    <unit>in</unit>
</vendorPackHeight>
<Weight>
    <measure>7.00</measure>
    <unit>LBS</unit> //invalid expected value is lb
</Weight>
```

When XSD validation fails for either unit or measure child element with an error like cvc-enumeration-valid when measure is not from a set of enum values or unit values fail with cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1 when the data type does not match how can I get the parent element? In the above xml it would be Weight.

In the SAXParseException I get the line number where the error occurs. Is it possible to get the element from the line number and then get its parent?

Comment: I end up forming the XML one by one with elements and validating in each step to confirm if the sub-element is valid or not.

It will be gr8 if there is any better solution for this.

Comment: It means that XML is not valid accorgind the schema. Would you attach the link for viewing the schema content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think there is a standard way of doing this in the Java API. However some libraries do allow you to sneek a peek at what element its currently on. For instance in the Apache Xerces implementation it supports getting the current node via

`getProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node")`

Checkout their documentation about that property at their website: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/properties.html#dom.current-element-node

---

The [Xerces library](http://xerces.apache.org/) is provided by your JDK by default but can also be imported into your project as a 3rd party library. I would recommend adding it if you MUST have it for running your application correctly. Heres a bit of sample code which validates a XML document to an XSD and gets the current node.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.apache.xerces.impl.Constants;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class XSDTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

        // our XSD, which defines 1 node  <TheNode> which must have decimal text content 
        byte [] schemaData = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
                + "<xs:schema xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"
                    + "<xs:simpleType name=\"theNodeType\">"
                        + "<xs:restriction base=\"xs:decimal\"/>"
                    + "</xs:simpleType>"
                    + "<xs:element name=\"TheNode\" type=\"theNodeType\"/>"
                + "</xs:schema>").getBytes();
        // our invalid xml
        byte [] xmlData = "<TheNode>123NotADecimal</TheNode>".getBytes();

        // parse schema
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(schemaData));
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);

        // build our document, must use document builder to enable xerces parser properties for DOM
        // Also must be a xerces implementation of the DBF, should be enabled by default in a standard java project but just to be verbose about it
        // pass in the full name of the DBF impl
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.class.getName(), XSDTest.class.getClassLoader());
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData));


        // configure our validator and parse the document.
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new MyErrorHandler(validator));
        validator.validate(new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement()));
    }

    private static class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
        private final Validator xsdValidator;

        public MyErrorHandler(Validator xsdValidator) {
            this.xsdValidator = xsdValidator;
        }
        @Override
        public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Warning on node: " + getCurrentNode());
            System.out.println(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Error on node: " + getCurrentNode());
            System.out.println(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Fatal on node: " + getCurrentNode());
            System.out.println(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }


        private Node getCurrentNode() throws SAXNotRecognizedException, SAXNotSupportedException {
            // get prop "http://apache.org/xml/properties/dom/current-element-node"
            // see https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/properties.html#dom.current-element-node
            return (Node)xsdValidator.getProperty(Constants.XERCES_PROPERTY_PREFIX + Constants.CURRENT_ELEMENT_NODE_PROPERTY);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Error on node: [TheNode: null]
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '123NotADecimal' is not a valid value for 'decimal'.
Error on node: [TheNode: null]
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '123NotADecimal' of element 'TheNode' is not valid.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you switched to Saxon as your schema validator, you would be able to find out this information.

When you validate an in-memory tree with Saxon, the ValidationFailure object includes a reference to the actual node where validation failed (from there you can obviously navigate to the parent node).

When you validate a SAX stream with Saxon, the ValidationFailure object includes a Path which is a structured object containing information about the node where the failure occurred, and about each of its ancestors. The information available for each ancestor includes the node kind, node name, and sibling position.